# Facebook share multi language

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, localization, meta-tags, multilingual

I have a web page that is available in several languages.
If you share on Facebook, that only the domain will always be written in the English og: desciption meta tags.

For example:

`www.example.com` default language from IP (English, Hungarian, etc.)
Eng `og:description`: best site
Hun `og:desctiption`: legjobb honlap
If I share this on FB like this working perfect:
`www.example.com/hu`
`www.example.com/en`

But if I share only domain `www.example.com`, the meta tag is always English.

One of the possible solutions would be:

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/en" language="en"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/hu" language="hu"/>
```

But I did not find anything on the net.

Comment: what exactly is the question? one url = one set of og tags.

Comment: You can not specify multiple `og:url`, that is not possible. And it is also not possible to have Facebook “select” a language to display the information in.

Comment: So if I have a multilang site I can share it only one language?
So it's really a pity to give so much money to facebook developers :)